# MySQL Create Table is Missing Rows

Tags: mysql

I am experiencing very strange behavior when creating MySQL tables.  Over 10% of my data unexpectedly goes missing, presumably during the Create Table process.

Attempting to create a table from a 85,000 row .csv file using RMYSql is resulting in MySQL reporting that the table created successfully, but upon checking there are only ~75,000 rows (not always the same number, but around 75,000 each time).

**Troubleshooting steps:**

1. Split data in half and created two separate tables (Table1 and
   Table2), each 42,500 rows.
2. **Query:**  Select * Table1 UNION Select * Table2 - returns the expected
   85,000 rows.
3. **Query:**  Create Table Table3 Select * Table1 UNION Select * Table2 -
   creates Table3, ***with only ~75,000 rows***.

As you can see, the Create Table Query is the exact same thing as the UNION query that returns 85,000 rows only it is trying to create a table from it.  For some reason, Create Table doesn't seem to create the entire table.

I could NOT replicate this behavior on a local MySQL instance.  It happens every single time I try it on a hosted instance though, so I'm looking to either solve myself or point the host in the right direction.

Where is this data going?  How can I troubleshoot this?

Screenshots of troubleshooting:
[Original Union Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQpan.png)

[Same Query with Create Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Cat.png)

[Resulting Table from Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAf9L.png)

Comment: You should use `UNION ALL`, because otherwise duplicates will get lost. When you use MySQL-client to do the selections, look for `...., x warning (..... sec)` at the end of the statement, and use `SHOW WARNINGS` to see those x warnings.

Comment: 1) Show complete `CREATE TABLE` for a table which you load the data into 2) Show an example of CSV file content (2-3 rows) 3) Check `SHOW WARNINGS;` immediately after LOAD DATA statement completed.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about SHOW WARNINGS.  I ran the CREATE TABLE query again using PHPMyadmin and got the same result.  I ran both SHOW WARNINGS as the next SQL statement but it didn't return anything (I could have done it wrong).  I'll post screenshots of the queries, the data has 400-some rows and im not sure of the best way to share it.  In terms of duplicates, the data is deduplicated already so there shouldn't be any.  Either way, UNION and UNION ALL have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Any possibility that duplicates are being dropped? If you perform a UNION rather than a UNION ALL that would eliminate duplicates. Have you checked whether the missing rows are randomly distributed or is the csv file getting truncated somehow when writing it to the host? Maybe there is some type of filesize limit or write limit for what can be imported into your host?

Just some ideas. Not entirely sure based on the context given.

Comment: Thank you!  Great suggestions - I should have mentioned I did try some of this.  I tried both UNION and UNION ALL to make sure - but I am certain that it's not duplicates being dropped.  It's not a random distribution, its always rows near the end of the file so I suspect truncation.  I can upload those rows in a seperate table just fine, but upon merging with the first table using the UNION things go missing - but only on CREATE TABLE, the query itself shows 85000